# localhost didn't send any data using cURL

Tags: php, curl, localhost, php-curl

I'm having issues runing a PHP script using the web browser on my computer.  The script is working fine when I test it on a web server using the web browser.  It doesn't work on localhost.

This is what I have:

**index.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

If I run this script using the Terminal (php index.php), the script works fine.
If I run this script using any web browser on my computer, it doesn't work:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

[image: web browser]

[image: terminal]

I have MacOS Big Sur.

All packages were installed using Homebrew (httpd, mariadb, php 8.1).
All my applications are running ok on localhost.

I reinstalled the apache and php twice.  I also test the script using PHP 7, same result.

I have been trying to fix this for two days now.  I don't know what to do anymore.  Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You cant execute files from the browser.  You need some sort of "Web Server" to serve the page.

Comment: @RohitGupta OP clearly mentioned Apache...

Comment: check your access, error httpd logs, possibly your php-fpm logs too if you have that enabled. Did you declare 'index.php' as a DirectoryIndex in your vhost ? Did you setup your vhost to have a '.php' handler, etc ... What is different between this project and your other project's setups.  Are you being fooled by a zealous browser that is strict with http vs https , but does not show you any information about it ? etc ... and good luck.  Sendgrid on localhost works for me with similar stack.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg all that you mentioned is done on my side.  The only difference between this project is that i am not be able to call an API (external website) using cURL.  Other than that is working just fantastic.  I don't know what else to do here.